# Why is my partial not being found?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, webstorm

I'm currently making a nodejs app and i'm having some trouble setting it up. I'm using Webstorm's project creator and selecting nodejs express app with handlebars as the engine. I'm also including express-handlebars. For some reason when I include a partial, it doesn't find it even though I specify what the partial folder is. Below is my setup:

App.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


// view engine setup
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({
  layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, "views/layouts"),
  partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, "views/partials"),
  defaultLayout: 'layout',
  extname: 'hbs'
});


//routes
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var products = require('./routes/products')

var app = express();



app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, "views"));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



app.use('/', index);
app.use('/products', products);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

This is my folder structure and my products.js route file as well as my handlebars view. When I navigate to the products page I get an error that says "partial productsinfo not found". I've tried everything and idk how to fix, would appreciate if someone could shed some light on what I'm doing wrong here. Just wanna fix this setup so I can finally start my side project. Thanks!

edit: ignore the .handlebars extension for the productinfo.handlebars partial, i changed the extension to try to get it to work but it did nothing. Now its back to productinfo.hbs and still not working.

[image]

Comment: You said the error is `partial productsinfo not found` but the filename isn't plural, just `productinfo`. Is that a typo? Do your other templates render fine? Also can you show where you are rendering `productinfo.hbs`?

Comment: @mscdex yea i'm afraid that was a typo, you can see where I'm rendering the partial productinfo.hbs in the attached screenshot. To answer your other questions, the views are rendering just fine, its just the partial that isnt being found for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure I figured out the reason, so apparently when you build the project with webstorm, it includes the hbs framework which is similar to the 'express-handlebars' framework. So when I included 'express-handlebars' they were conflicting and my app was using hbs for some reason. Idk how to fix other than just building the project from scratch and specifically including what i need rather than use webstorm's project builder. I deleted the hbs module but I'm now getting an error saying hbs isnt found, just cant seem to see where its trying to look for it.

Edit: Okay just fixed it, had to simply rename the extensions now that I got rid of the other hbs module. Working perfectly now. Moral of the story: make sure you pay attention to all the modules being added by webstorm or just add everything manually yourself lol.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning anything to this variable {{productinfo}} in the template. There is no issue with the route. Either remove this variable from the template or assign some value.

Answer (score -1):

Your `productinfo.handlebars` filename should instead be `productinfo.hbs`.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to rename it back to .hbs, I only renamed it to .handlebars to try it out in case the extension was the reason. It still doesnt find the partial even with extension .hbs, thats how it was originally.